# How to use .not selector on children in JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I wanted to make it so that when you hover on an item in a dropdown menu, all of the items besides the one you hover on change color. To get this effect, I tried to use .not() selector in JQuery but I am unsure how to select the specific child element (which is `h1` in this case).

I tried writing `.not(this).` as well as `.not(children)`... they didn't work. See the JQuery code.

```
<div>
  <h1>Lorem</h1>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">111</a>
    <a href="#">222</a>
    <a href="#">333</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Ipsum</h1>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">111</a>
    <a href="#">222</a>
    <a href="#">333</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Dolor</h1>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">111</a>
    <a href="#">222</a>
    <a href="#">333</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('div').mouseenter(
    function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown').slideDown(300);
      $('h1').css({
        'color': '#808080'
      });
    });
  $('div').mouseleave(
    function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown').slideUp(300);
      $('h1').css({
        'color': 'white'
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: So you want to change the `color` of it's siblings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').hover(
    function(event) {
      var siblings = $("div").not(this);
      $('.dropdown', siblings).slideDown(300);
      $('h1', siblings).css({
        'color': '#808080'
      });
    },
    function() {
      var siblings = $("div").not(this);
      $('.dropdown', siblings).slideUp(300);
      $('h1', siblings).css({
        'color': 'white'
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Lorem</h1>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">111</a>
    <a href="#">222</a>
    <a href="#">333</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Ipsum</h1>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">111</a>
    <a href="#">222</a>
    <a href="#">333</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Dolor</h1>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">111</a>
    <a href="#">222</a>
    <a href="#">333</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This only works as expected after the first `hover` event. We use the same selector and then remove `this` from the group. Now the items act as expected.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: It works, although if you write `('.dropdown', siblings)` then it will trigger all dropdown menus instead of the one underneath the hovered item, so I instead wrote `('.dropdown', this)` and now it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your problem right, try this:

```
    $(function () {
    $('div').mouseenter(
        function () {
            $(this).find('.dropdown').slideDown(300);
            $('h1').not(this).css({ 'color': '#808080' });
            $(this).find('h1').css({ 'color': 'white' });
        });
    $('div').mouseleave(
        function () {
            $(this).find('.dropdown').slideUp(300);
            $('h1').css({ 'color': 'white' });
        });
});
```